# mongoDB lookup command returns all the collections if not match found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two model called **Brand.js** and **Item.js**
The brand is linked to the item like this

**Item.js**

```
brandId: Number,
    size: String,
    description: String,
```

When I run this aggregation

```
 let data = await Item.aggregate([
      {$match:{}},

      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "brands",
          localField: "brandId",
          foreignField: "id",
          as: "brand",
        },
      },
      
    
 
     
    ]);
```

If there is a brand it will return the relevant brand. If `brandId` is `null`. It will return all of the documents in the brand collection. If `brandId` is `null` it should return an empty array. Why could this happen?

This works as a right outer join. I want to run this as a left outer join.

Answer (score 0):

you can add reference to the brand in Item.js like this `brandId: { type: Number, ref: 'Brand' }`
Then your query will be

```
Item.find().populate('brandId');
```

[Mongoose Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)